# I need help for making a simple java plugin function for Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

I don't have developing knowledge and still i wanted to do sth fairly easy i guess. But on my own I just lack the experience.

So what i wanted to do:

I want to write a plugin for a minecraft server.
It's because I have an idea for my gaming stream.

I wanted to have a challenge (in game) where when I break a block in Minecraft there is a 50% chance to randomly teleport me.

Or even easier.

Just a plugin or script that detects the block break event in minecraft by player (me) and forces the console to run a command "sudo Moruga rtp"

thats basically it.

I would be really happy if you guys could help me with that.

The reason why I dont hire anyone to do that are the following:

1. I am a student and don't have the budged availible.
2. I want to do more projects like this in the future and I want to do "learning by doing"

Best regards,
Jannik

(I am very sorry for my bad english, I am not a native english speaker)

Comment: Hey @Jannik, this post might get removed soon since it's broad, but I recommend checking out some YouTube tutorials first. If you have a specific issue, you can always come back and look it up/ask. Good luck with your project

Comment: @JonathanS. Yeah that's true I guess, but I already checked youtube and did some research. I have found nothing about how to execute a command if any block will be broken. 

But yeah I will do some more research and if I get a specific problem as you have told me I will come back ^^

Comment: [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) is one of the best resources for beginning Java developers there has ever been. When you have more experience, you can just "try stuff" in new languages because you already have a sense of how code and software development works, but for now, there are no shortcuts.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Thank you very much! I will read into it and learn the basic of Java coding and then I will look how far I can push myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void rndTeleport(Player p) {
  Location loc = p.getLocation();
  Block highest = p.getWorld().getHighestBlockAt(loc.getBlockX(), loc.getBlockZ());
  Random rnd = new Random();
  double x = rnd.nextInt((100000 - 1) + 1);
  double z = rnd.nextInt((100000 - 1) + 1);
  p.teleport(new Location(p.getWorld(), x, highest.getLocation().getBlockY()+1, z)));
}
```

So I've made this by hand on stackoverflow.
You should define the rnd somewhere else and you could find a better solution for the x and y coordinates. But it's working.

An example of the block break event can be found here
[Bukkit blockbreak event](https://bukkit.org/threads/block-break-event.111127/)